# Using custom Dapper ITypeHandler for parsing data but not for handling SQL parameters

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

Assume there is a stored procedure `sp_legacy` that is not possible to change. The result set contains, among other things, a column called `Ids`. The column carries a list of integers as `JSON`. An example result set with three rows could look like this:

```
Ids
'[1, 2, 3]'
'[2, 3, 4]'
'[-1, 0, 42]'
```

Dapper is used to execute `sp_legacy` and map the result to the class `LegacyRow`:

```
public class LegacyRow
{
    public IEnumerable<int> { get; set; }
}
```

To accomplish this a type handler is used:

```
public class JsonTypeHandler : SqlMapper.ITypeHandler
{
    public object Parse(Type destinationType, object value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.Deserialize((string)value, destinationType);
    }

    public void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which is registered using the `IEnumerable<int>` type:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(IEnumerable<int>), new JsonTypeHandler());
```

This makes it possible to do something like the below. This is desirable, it should be easy to query.

```
var rows = await DbConnection.QueryAsync<LegacyRow>("sp_legacy", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

However, this has the nasty unintended side effect that SQL parameters of type `IEnumerable<int>` will be handled by `JsonTypeHandler`. For example this will cause a `NotImplementedException` to be thrown in `JsonTypeHandler.SetValue`:

```
IEnumerable<int> ids = ...
await Dapper.ExecuteAsync("select * from foo where Id in @Ids", new { Ids = ids }, CommandType.Text);
```

What alternatives are there for keeping the automatic deserialization of the `Ids` column while not modifying the default handling of `IEneumerable<int>` SQL parameters?